# Show Direction Arrows On GreatMaps Route

Tags: direction, arrows, gmap.net

I am using Greatmaps in a Windows Forms application. I have markers and routes showing but want to add some arrows along the routes to show the direction of travel. I can add GMarkerGoogleType.arrow markers but even if I set the Bearing property of the markers the arrows always point south.

How can I rotate the markers to match the heading ?

Ideally I would like to see just small triangles along the route line which are the same colour as the route stroke colour. Is this possible ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a **Custom Marker** (**GMarkerArrow**) instead of (**GMarkerGoogleType.arrow**) because the support of bearing property of the arrow has been deprecated in this class.

To get the custom marker class, you can found it in the **Demo app** (**Demo.WindowsForms**) they created in this link [GMarkerArrow Marker Class](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/blob/master/Demo.WindowsForms/CustomMarkers/GMarkerArrow.cs) and you can set the bearing property to it.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed, your answer allowed me to add nice arrows that listened to the Bearing property. In case this helps anyone else my final solution involved calculating the midpoint between two points and the bearing between those points and I added an arrow marker at this calculated point with the calculated bearing. So now I have arrows halfway between each point on my route which is what I wanted to achieve..